# Python 3.9 import issue

Tags: python-3.9

I just installed Python 3.9 with the Windows 64-bit installer. For some reason the all of the modules I had previously installed using `pip` will no longer import, unless I am running Python from the directory where they are located: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages`

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the `requests` module with `pip` and then importing `requests` in a shell, still not recognized.

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I imagine this is probably some environmental variable path issue. I'm new to Python, any help getting this straightened out much appreciated.

Comment: How are you installing `requests` in 3.9 ?. `pip install requests` ?

Comment: @LeelaPrasad yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each version of python has its own global sites package directory where it stores the packages you install.

Ex: Python 3.8 will store under %appdata%\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages

Python 3.9 would store it in a different location (like Python39-32)

In order to install a package for specific version of python you need to install it with python version command.

```
py -3.9 -m pip install requests
```

You can refer the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/)

Comment: There is no `python3.9` on Windows, the binary is just called `python.exe`. You need to use `py -3.9` to preferentially run the correct version.